# What does the non-uniqueness of the Task.Id property mean?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

On [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id?view=net-6.0#remarks) says:

> Note that although collisions are very rare, task identifiers are not
> guaranteed to be unique.

Does this mean that there can be tasks with the same IDs in the heap at the same time? Or does it mean that it can't be, but there are tasks with IDs that other tasks already had that no longer exist?

Comment: What is the reason for accessing a task's Id in the first place?

Comment: @gunr2171, Do not know. I'm new at this.

Comment: Unless you're planning to use a task's id for something, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Just take the surface reading of it - if you were planning to use the ID as some form of unique identifier, you know now that's not appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if you create 4,294,967,295 tasks, and read the [`Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id) property of each one of them, the first and the last task will both have the value 1 as `Id`.

You can see the source code of the `Task.Id` property [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs.html#784864bc4dc294af). Below is the essence of this code:

```
public class Task
{
    private volatile int m_taskId;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_taskId == 0)
            {
                int newId = NewId();
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_taskId, newId, 0);
            }
            return m_taskId;
        }
    }

    internal static int s_taskIdCounter;

    internal static int NewId()
    {
        int newId = 0;
        do
        {
            newId = Interlocked.Increment(ref s_taskIdCounter);
        }
        while (newId == 0);
        return newId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at the source code yet. In other words - yes, it's possible - we can have multiple tasks running at the same time with ID 1. Right?

Comment: @NikVladi yeap, exactly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I checked it, it took time, but yes. In this case, the task ID changes within the int32 range, that is, sometimes it is negative. And at some point, several tasks with the same id are running.